# How to find transactions with same transacrionTo

Tags: sql, db2

Let's say we have a table called Transaction. Each transaction has an id(key), a transactionFrom(number) and a transactionTo(number). How can I find all the transactions that have for the same transactionTo different transactionFrom?

Here is some sample data and some expected results:

id | transactionFrom | transactionTo

1 |  12345           | 54321

2 | 38906            | 54321

3 | 21398 | 12098

4 | 00000 | 22222

5 | 00000 | 22222

6 | 11111 | 33333

7 | 44444 | 33333

the desired results for this sample data is:

id | transactionFrom | transactionTo

1 | 12345 | 54321

2 | 38906 | 54321

6 | 11111 | 33333

7 | 44444 | 33333

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Also let us know what you have tried till now

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

`select  a.id, a.transactionFrom , a.transactionTo
from txn A
inner join txn B
on A.transactionTo = B.transactionTo
and A.id <> B.id
and A.transactionFrom <> B.transactionFrom
with ur;`

Comment: By definition, `A.transactionFrom <> B.transactionFrom` will mean that `A.id <> B.id` is always true (unnecessary clause).  One thing to note is that if there's more than two records rows will appear to be duplicated (multiple instances of the same `A/B.id`) - it's unclear if that's the case, which would necessitate some sort of initial aggregation.